# How to resize/change webview height based on it's content in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

I am using webview in a recycler view. so I need to resize the webview based on it's content.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is to change the visibility of webview after reloading the content.

`mWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
mWebView.loadData(".....");
mWebView.reload();
mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`